# Creating two drawer and one tab navigator in the same screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I've a screen which has two drawer navigation. It was possible to handle two drawers in v1 but it is not working anymore.

I also want to add one tab navigator to the same screen but I got stuck with the problem above.

How can I use two drawers in one screen using react navigation v2

Here is my route config :

```
export const MainStack = createStackNavigator({
    Home: {
        screen: HomeContainer,
        navigationOptions: { header: null },
    },
    NewsList: {
        screen: NewsList,
        navigationOptions: { header: null },
    },
    NewsDetail: {
        screen: NewsDetail,
        path: 'news/:itemId',
        navigationOptions: { header: null },
    },
  },
  {
    mode: 'card',
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
    drawerBackgroundColor: '#151515',
    drawerPosition: 'right',
    drawerWidth: 80,
  },
);



export const MainDrawer = createDrawerNavigator({
    MainStack,
  },

  {
    initialRouteName: 'MainStack',
    drawerBackgroundColor: '#151515',
    drawerPosition: 'left',
    drawerWidth: 80,
    contentComponent: props => <LeftMenuContainer {...props} />,
    drawerOpenRoute: 'LeftSideMenu',
    drawerCloseRoute: 'LeftSideMenuClose',
    drawerToggleRoute: 'LeftSideMenuToggle',
  },
);

export const Root = createDrawerNavigator({
    MainStack
  },
  {
    navigationOptions: {
    },
    drawerBackgroundColor: '#151515',
    drawerPosition: 'right',
    drawerWidth: 80,
    contentComponent: props => <MenuContainer {...props} />,
    drawerOpenRoute: 'RightSideMenu',
    drawerCloseRoute: 'RightSideMenuClose',
    drawerToggleRoute: 'RightSideMenuToggle',
  },
);
```

Answer (score 0):

## There should be a hierarchy

Pass MainDrawer to Root as a screen.

```
export const MainStack = createStackNavigator({
    Home: {
        screen: HomeContainer,
        navigationOptions: { header: null },
    },
    NewsList: {
        screen: NewsList,
        navigationOptions: { header: null },
    },
    NewsDetail: {
        screen: NewsDetail,
        path: 'news/:itemId',
        navigationOptions: { header: null },
    },
  },
  {
    mode: 'card',
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
    drawerBackgroundColor: '#151515',
    drawerPosition: 'right',
    drawerWidth: 80,
  },
);



export const MainDrawer = createDrawerNavigator({
    MainStack,
  },

  {
    initialRouteName: 'MainStack',
    drawerBackgroundColor: '#151515',
    drawerPosition: 'left',
    drawerWidth: 80,
    contentComponent: props => <LeftMenuContainer {...props} />,
    drawerOpenRoute: 'LeftSideMenu',
    drawerCloseRoute: 'LeftSideMenuClose',
    drawerToggleRoute: 'LeftSideMenuToggle',
  },
);

export const Root = createDrawerNavigator({
    MainDrawer
  },
  {
    navigationOptions: {
    },
    drawerBackgroundColor: '#151515',
    drawerPosition: 'right',
    drawerWidth: 80,
    contentComponent: props => <MenuContainer {...props} />,
    drawerOpenRoute: 'RightSideMenu',
    drawerCloseRoute: 'RightSideMenuClose',
    drawerToggleRoute: 'RightSideMenuToggle',
  },
);
```

Comment: When I wrote the routes this way and try to open drawer using this.props.navigation.openDrawer(); it is always opening MainDrawer which is on the left, I could not figure out any parameter to target left drawer or right drawer

Comment: Ah yest I see, hmmmm thats quite a problem with the new setup.

Comment: Do you have any idea about what I should do?